# Сделать так, что бы новый список не выводился полностью

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для возможности добавлять ветки, решил сначала поэкспериментировать, скажем так "собственноручно" создать ее. Но после нажатия кнопки появился второй список с уже добавленным элементом. Я то понимаю почему так произошло, но никак не могу додуматься сделать, так, что бы выводилась только новая ветка, а не целый "обновленный" список. Или может для этого вообще нужно написать новую функцию? Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_1',
      addInputId: 'a_1',
      liId: 'l_1'
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: '1',
      deleteInputId: 'd_2',
      addInputId: 'a_2',
      liId: 'l_2'
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2",
      itemParentId: 1,
      deleteInputId: 'd_3',
      addInputId: 'a_3',
      liId: 'l_3'
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "пункт №2",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_4',
      addInputId: 'a_4',
      liId: 'l_4'
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "пункт №3",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_5',
      addInputId: 'a_5',
      liId: 'l_5'
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "пункт №3.1",
      itemParentId: 5,
      deleteInputId: 'd_6',
      addInputId: 'a_6',
      liId: 'l_6'
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "пункт №3.2",
      itemParentId: 5,
      deleteInputId: 'd_7',
      addInputId: 'a_7',
      liId: 'l_7'
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3",
      itemParentId: 5,
      deleteInputId: 'd_8',
      addInputId: 'a_8',
      liId: 'l_8'
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "пункт №4",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_9',
      addInputId: 'a_9',
      liId: 'l_9'
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "пункт №5",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_10',
      addInputId: 'a_10',
      liId: 'l_10'
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "пункт №5.1",
      itemParentId: 10,
      deleteInputId: 'd_11',
      addInputId: 'a_11',
      liId: 'l_11'
    }

  ]
}

function createTree(data, parentId) {
  parentId = parentId || 0;
  var items = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.itemParentId == parentId;
  });
  if (items.length == 0) return null;
  var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
  tree.append(
    
    items.map(
      function(el) {

        var li = $('<li>').append(
            $('<input>').attr({type: 'checkbox', id: el.deleteInputId})
          ).append(
            $('<label>').html(el.itemName).attr({id: el.itemId, for: el.deleteInputId}).addClass('item')
          ).append(
            $('<a>').addClass('state')
          ).attr({id: el.liId}),
          nestedTree = createTree(data, el.itemId);
        if (nestedTree !== null) {
          li.append(nestedTree)
            .addClass('collapse');
        }
        return li;
      }
    )
  );
  return tree;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tree = createTree(listCategories.data);
  $('#tree').append(
    $('<input type="button" id="deleteBranch" value="Delete">')
  ).append(
    $('<input type="button" id="addBranch" value="Add">')
  ).append(tree)
            .on('dblclick', '.item',function(){
                $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
            })

            .on('click', '.item',function(){
                $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            })

            .on('click', '.state',function(){
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
            })

          .on('click', '#addBranch', function() {
            listCategories['data'].push({itemId: 12, 
                                         itemName: "пункт №6", 
                                         itemParentId: 0, 
                                         deleteInputId: 'd_12',
                                         addInputId: 'a_12', 
                                         liId: 'l_12'});
            var tree_2 = createTree(listCategories.data);
            $('#tree').append(tree_2)
        })
});
```

```css
ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.collapse > .state::after {
  content: '+';
}
.expand > .state::after {
  content: '-';
}
.collapse > ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand > ul {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#addBranch {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#deleteBranch {
  margin-rigth: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо новых функций. Просто удалите существующее дерево перед тем, как `append` новое:

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_1',
      addInputId: 'a_1',
      liId: 'l_1'
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: '1',
      deleteInputId: 'd_2',
      addInputId: 'a_2',
      liId: 'l_2'
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2",
      itemParentId: 1,
      deleteInputId: 'd_3',
      addInputId: 'a_3',
      liId: 'l_3'
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "пункт №2",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_4',
      addInputId: 'a_4',
      liId: 'l_4'
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "пункт №3",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_5',
      addInputId: 'a_5',
      liId: 'l_5'
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "пункт №3.1",
      itemParentId: 5,
      deleteInputId: 'd_6',
      addInputId: 'a_6',
      liId: 'l_6'
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "пункт №3.2",
      itemParentId: 5,
      deleteInputId: 'd_7',
      addInputId: 'a_7',
      liId: 'l_7'
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3",
      itemParentId: 5,
      deleteInputId: 'd_8',
      addInputId: 'a_8',
      liId: 'l_8'
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "пункт №4",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_9',
      addInputId: 'a_9',
      liId: 'l_9'
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "пункт №5",
      itemParentId: 0,
      deleteInputId: 'd_10',
      addInputId: 'a_10',
      liId: 'l_10'
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "пункт №5.1",
      itemParentId: 10,
      deleteInputId: 'd_11',
      addInputId: 'a_11',
      liId: 'l_11'
    }

  ]
}

function createTree(data, parentId) {
  parentId = parentId || 0;
  var items = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.itemParentId == parentId;
  });
  if (items.length == 0) return null;
  var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
  tree.append(

    items.map(
      function(el) {

        var li = $('<li>').append(
          $('<input>').attr({type: 'checkbox', id: el.deleteInputId})
        ).append(
          $('<label>').html(el.itemName).attr({id: el.itemId, for: el.deleteInputId}).addClass('item')
        ).append(
          $('<a>').addClass('state')
        ).attr({id: el.liId}),
            nestedTree = createTree(data, el.itemId);
        if (nestedTree !== null) {
          li.append(nestedTree)
            .addClass('collapse');
        }
        return li;
      }
    )
  );
  return tree;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tree = createTree(listCategories.data);

  $('#tree')
    .append(
      $('<input type="button" id="deleteBranch" value="Delete">')
    )
    
    .append(
      $('<input type="button" id="addBranch" value="Add">')
    ).
  
    append(tree)

    .on('dblclick', '.item', function(){
      $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
    })

    .on('click', '.item',function(){
      $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    })

    .on('click', '.state',function(){
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
    })

    .on('click', '#addBranch', function() {
      listCategories['data'].push({itemId: 12, 
                                 itemName: "пункт №6", 
                                 itemParentId: 0, 
                                 deleteInputId: 'd_12',
                                 addInputId: 'a_12', 
                                 liId: 'l_12'});
      
      var tree_2 = createTree(listCategories.data);
      
      $('#tree').find('.tree').remove().end().append(tree_2);
    });
});
```

```css
ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.collapse > .state::after {
  content: '+';
}
.expand > .state::after {
  content: '-';
}
.collapse > ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand > ul {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#addBranch {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#deleteBranch {
  margin-rigth: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! А я уж принялся функцию создавать :D